# Why am I not able to view the clone() system call in strace output when typing 'strace ls' in terminal?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, ls, strace

My understanding is that when we type `ls` in the terminal:

1. It invokes `fork()` library function which invokes system call `clone()`
   to create a child process.
2. Then system call `execve()` is invoked to replace address space of the new process created with new content.

In that case I was expecting to see system calls `clone()` and `execve()` in   the `strace` ls output. But I am seeing only `execve()` and not `clone()`.

What could be reason?

I tried the following commands:

```
strace ls
strace -c ls
strace -f ls
```

OS - Redhat

Comment: Try `strace strace ls` for enlightenment.  `strace` only starts tracing the process after it's already been forked.  This is really the only way it can work, you can't trace a process that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true, your shell does `fork` + `execve` to execute a command, but you are not tracing your shell, so you will not see it!

The `strace` tool simply creates a child (through `fork`), attaches to it with `ptrace` and then does `execve` of the requested command, so if you do a simple `strace ls` the first thing that you will see is the `execve` done by `strace` to start `ls`.

If you want to see *what your shell does*, you can start a shell and then attach to it from another shell with `strace`.

1. Start one shell, then get its PID (in bash just `echo $$` will get you the current shell PID).
2. Start a second shell, and run `strace -f -p PID_OF_FIRST_SHELL`.
3. Execute `ls` in the first shell, and whatch the output of `strace` on the second one.

Note that since `strace` traces every syscall by default, and shells are usually very complex programs, you will see a lot of syscalls in the output. If you want to just observe a few syscalls, you can filter them with the `-e` option, for example:

```
strace -e clone,fork,execve -f -p PID_OF_FIRST_SHELL
```

---

Example on my machine:

- Shell 1:

  ```
  root@desktop:~/test# echo $$
  30878
  root@desktop:~/test# ls -l
  total 0
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 15 00:21 a
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 15 00:21 b
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 15 00:21 c
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 15 00:21 d
  ```
- Shell 2:

  ```
  root@desktop:~/test# strace -e clone,fork,execve -f -p 30878
  strace: Process 30878 attached
  clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f070ece0a10) = 30958
  strace: Process 30958 attached
  [pid 30958] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "--color=auto", "-l"], 0x55c87a5cb9f0 /* 22 vars */) = 0
  [pid 30958] +++ exited with 0 +++
  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=30958, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
  clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f070ece0a10) = 30959
  strace: Process 30959 attached
  [pid 30959] +++ exited with 0 +++
  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=30959, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
  ...
  ```